# GeoPandas geodataframe.cx() coordinate indexing not working for multipolygon

Tags: python, geopandas, indexing, plotting

I am trying to apply the coordinate indexing .cx method to a GeoPandas geodataframe with a multipolygon geometry. I would like to plot a part of the full polygon. So far I have:

```
NP_shp.crs
<Projected CRS: EPSG:3577>
Name: GDA94 / Australian Albers
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: Australia - Australian Capital Territory; New South    Wales; Northern Territory; Queensland; South Australia; Tasmania; Western Australia; Victoria.
- bounds: (112.85, -43.7, 153.69, -9.86)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: Australian Albers
- method: Albers Equal Area
Datum: Geocentric Datum of Australia 1994
- Ellipsoid: GRS 1980
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich


type(NP_shp)
geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame
NP_shp.total_bounds
array([150.1660361 , -33.90058926, 150.643035  , -33.36346718])
```

The total_bounds after applying the .cx coordinate indexing remain exactly the same:

```
NP_shp.cx[:150.3,:-33.5].total_bounds
array([150.1660361 , -33.90058926, 150.643035  , -33.36346718])
```

Similarly, `NP_shp.cx[:150.3,:-33.5].plot()` gives identical output to `NP_shp.plot()`.

I have followed the example in the GeoPandas documentation for indexing using .cx (https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/indexing.html), which works fine.

Perhaps the problem is something to do with my original shapefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.cx` doesnt clip the input geometry, it selects all rows/geometries that intersects the limits. So if one small polygon part of a multipolygon intersects, the entire multipolygon will be selected.

You can import matplotlib and [set x and y limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014498/how-to-restrict-a-geopandas-plot-by-coordinates) of the plot.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

australia = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\Australia.geojson")
print(australia.shape)
#(1, 8)
print(australia.total_bounds)
#[112.90720923 -54.75389102 158.96037238 -10.13569092]
australia.plot(color="blue")
```

[image]

```
#Try to plot only Tasmania using .cx
ymin, xmin = -43.8911,144.4329
ymax, xmax = -39.6875,149.8590
tasmania = australia.cx[xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax]
print(tasmania.total_bounds)
#[112.90720923 -54.75389102 158.96037238 -10.13569092] #Same bounds.
tasmania.plot(color="green")
```

[image]

Set x and y limits:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
tasmania.plot(ax=ax, color="red")
ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
```

[image]